# Tkinter: How to create choice box

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, box

I need to create a choice box 
 [image: choice box] 
 where i can click on arrow and it give me list of choices. 
[image: choice box pic 2]

And if i click on one of them it will change it in that first rectangle. 
Its possible to do something like this?
Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Sounds like you want a ListBox widget.

Comment: can you guys post any easy example where i can understand how work with that ?

Comment: How about you try it and post some code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also try an [`OptionMenu`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm):

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

choices = ['GB', 'MB', 'KB']
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set('GB')

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *choices)
w.pack(); root.mainloop()
```

[image: OptionMenu example]

Or you can try using a `Combobox`:

```
from ttk import *
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

choices = ['GB', 'MB', 'KB']
variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set('GB')

w = Combobox(root, values = choices)
w.pack(); root.mainloop()
```

[image: Combobox example]

Comment: Drop the semicolon ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

Tkinter has two widgets that do what you want. One is [OptionMenu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) and the other is [ttk.Combobox](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#combobox).

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        choiceVar = tk.StringVar()
        choices = ("choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3", "choice 4")
        choiceVar.set(choices[0])

        om = tk.OptionMenu(self, choiceVar, *choices)
        cb = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=choiceVar, values=choices)

        om.pack()
        cb.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: ComboBox and OptionMenu]

Answer (score -1):

There is a [class](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/569150-how-add-drop-down-box-python-gui) that someone made for a drop down list view. Using this class, you can try:

```
from Tkinter import *

# insert class here

root = Tk()

view = ChoiceBox(root, ['MB', 'KB', 'GB', 'TB'])
view.place_configure(x = 0, y = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: because a) there are built-in widgets that do what the OP wants, and b) it forces the reader to go to another site, and then scroll through a bunch of responses to find the code.

Comment: You can also use an option menu which you can see in another answer below. You had no trouble with the class right?

Comment: Bryan Oakley, I made another answer including an option menu. And for the record, scrolling is not an inconvenience. This profession is one in which you have to exert a slight amount of effort. And you're link answer isn't much better.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: it's not so much the inconvenience of scrolling. Answers that link to code on other websites are against the spirit of stackoverflow. That other site could go down or get reorganized and then your answer becomes completely useless. Plus, all of the discussion you linked to is misleading because it is so old. A beginner who reads that may get the impression there are no built-in widgets that do what they want, when in fact there is not just one, but two.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Merge this answer with the other. No need to have 2 answers from the same person, it creates more confusion, in my opinion.